# Get xml with HTTPRequest in a page without an xml file extension

Tags: jquery, xml, httprequest

I am trying to use an HTTPRequest using jquerys ajax function to get the xml from a page. The function is not returning anything.  My theory of why this is not working is because the page I am hitting has the file extension ".ns" rather than ".xml"  This is the FULL page source of the page I am hitting.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<logged_in_reps>
</logged_in_reps>
```

How can I get this XML from an HTTPRequest?

Some additional information that may help: When I save the webpage it saves as "command.ns.xml" (which the url only has the .ns and not the .xml) and when I hit this page in the same directory as my own file (with the .xml extension) that has the request, it works fine.

Also the domain that the file making the request is on is "www.csun.edu" and the page i'm hitting is on "remotesupport.csun.edu". Could this be a problem?

Here is the code to make the call (unfortunately I cannot provide the username and password with the url I am hitting)

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://remotesupport.csun.edu/api/command.ns?username=user&password=pass&action=get_logged_in_reps',
    type: 'GET',
    datatype: 'xml',
    success: function(xml) {
        alert(xml);
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the requests that are made when you visit that url in a browser using Firebug? There maybe be a redirection or something. Also, have you tried downloading as datatype 'text' to see what happens?

Comment: Yeah I used firebug to check out the response and request there is not redirection. And in firebug it says for the XML "XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{23e8ddc5-bc72-4c7e-8e5f-79e181071896} Line Number 1, Column 1:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get round the Same Origin Policy issue, and the fact that the server you want to get the XML from doesn't support JSONP, you can use YQL.

[Here's an example](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20%2a%20from%20xml%20where%20url=%22http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=test%22)

You would then use this as the URL for your JSONP request:

`http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from xml where url="http://the-xml-url.com"`

So for you problem you would do something like this:

```
yql_url = function(source_url) {
  return "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from xml where url=\"" + source_url + "\"";
};

$.ajax({
    url: yql_url('https://remotesupport.csun.edu/api/command.ns?username=user&password=pass&action=get_logged_in_reps'),
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(xml) {
        console.log($(xml).find('result'));
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean? What do you want to do that you can't do with this method?

Comment: I work for a school. After I used this method they told me we can put anything out in production that sends data to something we don't control

Comment: Unless you can get csun.edu's API to support JSONP, then you have no choice but to use a proxy. Many people use YQL because it is fast and reliable. If you are not allowed to use their service, then the only other option is to host your own proxy.

Comment: A proxy would be very easy to implement. All you need to do is handle 2 parameters with each request. The url and the callback. You then download the data from the url, and insert it as a string into a javascript function named after the callback parameter. Eg. `callbackname("<thexmldata></thexmldata>")`. You then just return that as the response.

Comment: Yeah setting up a proxy is going to be a last resort just because I can't set that up myself so I have to get someone with more access to do it.  Thank you for the help Acorn. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main problems.

First, you are denied access to that XML file because of [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Second, the `dataType` argument must be used as that exact string.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the problem is the security restriction called [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

You can circumvent it using the JSONP technique (see JQuery support explained [here](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/)), but that requires you to wrap the generated XML output.

Another solution is to proxy your Ajax request through the origin server (that is, `www.csun.edu` in your case).

Comment: If firebug shows a syntax error on the page i'm hitting does that mean JSONP isn't supported? This is the code i'm using
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  url: "https://remotesupport.csun.edu/api/command.ns?username=user&password=pass&action=get_logged_in_reps",
  success: function (res) {
    alert(res);
  },
});

Comment: Please note (as mentioned above), that the API response needs to be adapted to work as JSONP. The posted Jquery link briefly explains how the response needs to look (it's interpreted as JavaScript!). [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671143/is-there-an-existing-tool-for-jsonp-like-fetching-of-xml-in-jquery) provides a discussion to pass XML via JSONP.