# Problems using jQuery AJAX to parse XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

I'm not a very experience programmer and have been learning HTML/CSS/JS on the fly.  I've been trying to parse XML using jQuery AJAX methods with absolutely no luck.

Here is my code in use: http://jsfiddle.net/Kb5qj/1/

And here is my code in plain sight:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var divid = "#xmlcontent"

function parseXML(xml) {
    $(divid).empty();
    $(xml).find("CD").each(function() {
        var artist = $(this).find("ARTIST").text();
        var title = $(this).find("TITLE").text();
        $(divid).append("<li>" + artist + " - " + title + "</li>");
    });
}

function printError() {
    $(divid).html("An error occurred");
}

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "www.w3schools.com/ajax/cd_catalog.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseXML,
    error: printError
});
});
```

I don't know what the problem could be.  I have written and re-written and copy/pasted that $.ajax call many many times, but no matter what I do nothing ever happens.  Help me please?

Comment: FYI get requests dnt work in jsfiddle. You need to mock it.. look at the examples stated there.

Comment: You cannot load XML from another domain:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942673/get-xml-data-cross-domain-with-jquery

Comment: Thanks for the responses so far.  This poses a new problem; how do I test code that I write on my local system?  I plan to use my knowledge of parsing XML to write an RSS headlines gadget for a Google Site (I've been using my code in the Google Gadget Editor with moderate success, apart from these AJAX requests).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like I mentioned it will fail on jsfiddle as they dnt actually send the get request. here is the api on how to achieve the same: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html

If you try the same on your local system it will fail probably cos you are making a cross domain request and your browser natively blocks such requests. That is where jsonp comes it to play its to retrieve json data over cross domains..

You can hack it a little to do the same for js.. here is a SO post about the same: [Is there an existing tool for jsonp like fetching of xml in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671143/is-there-an-existing-tool-for-jsonp-like-fetching-of-xml-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

With a little bit of fudging, everything **in the parsing** seems to work fine.  [Check out this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jtVgm/6/).

You can't use get requests from JSFiddle, but I mocked up the XML into HTML.  You may want to try placing your XML document into the DOM to help suss your issue.